# How to parse/filter log line with awk or sed

Tags: heroku, sed, awk

I am trying to find out how to filter heroku log drains using awk, sed or some other tool. As you can see the examples below, the command filters the lines with `grep` related to the `router` only. But I could not figure out how to filter the rest.

`heroku logs -t | grep router |`  ???

> 2013-07-20T20:44:40.855998+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/oauth2/callback?error=access_denied host=app.herokuapp.com fwd="123.234.456.78" dyno=web.5 connect=1ms service=55ms status=302 bytes=5
>
> 2013-07-20T20:44:40.855998+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/oauth2/callback/succesuser=%7B%22user%3Aexample%40example.com%22%2C%22force%22%3Afalse%7D host=app.herokuapp.com fwd="123.234.456.78" dyno=web.5 connect=1ms service=312ms status=302 bytes=5

*Question 1)* There is a part that gives detail about the service time in the log lines: (`service=55ms` and `service=312ms` from the examples) Let's say I want to see only the ones with service time more than 300ms. How can I achive that?

*Optional Question)* Is there any chance that I can format these lines comma separated like this: `timestamp,path,service`

Example outputs for the optional question:

> 2013-07-20 20:44:40,/oauth2/callback?error=access_denied,55`
>
> 2013-07-20 20:44:40,/oauth2/callback/succesuser=%7B%22user%3Aexample%40example.com%22%2C%22force%22%3Afalse%7D,312`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use awk. Put this in a file awk0:

```
BEGIN       {OFS = ","}

            {split($10,arr,"\="); time = arr[2] + 0}

time > 300  {print $1, $5, time}
```

Then this should work:

```
heroku logs -t | grep router | awk -f awk0
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

See if this sed expression is of any use:

```
sed '/[3-9][0-9][0-9][m][s]/!d'
sed '/[3-9][0-9][0-9][m][s]/!d
```

Here's an example:

```
printf '301ms\n300ms\n302ms\n200ms\n40ms' | sed '/[3-9][0-9][0-9][m][s]/!d'

=> 301ms
=> 300ms
=> 302ms
```

To get only those lines with **more** than 300ms, use this instead:

```
sed '/[3-9][0-9][1-9]/!d'
```

Another example:

```
printf '301ms\n300ms\n302ms\n200ms\n40ms' | sed '/[3-9][0-9][1-9][m][s]/!d'

=> 301ms
=> 302ms
```

The reason why the above--this `/[3-9][0-9][1-9]/!d`--also filters out numbers smaller than 300, is because of the `!` flaggy thingy--it tells sed to delete all lines that don't match the pattern `[3-9][0-9][1-9][m][s]`.

Comment: great, thanks for the demo. That helps clarify! Good luck to all.

Comment: I guess that would filter out from 100 to 300. If service time is less than 100ms, then they are still not filtered out.